# Prove $|f(x)|=c\{1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1\cdot 3\cdots(2n-3)}{2\cdot 6\cdots 2n}(1-\frac{f^2(x)}{c^2})^n \}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In the process of reading, I discovered a recipe but I don't know how the author made it, looking forward to everyone's help.

With $c \geq 1 $, $|f(x)|=\sqrt{c^2-[c^2-f^2(x)]}=c\sqrt{1-(1-\frac{f^2(x)}{c^2})}=c\{1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1\cdot 3\cdots(2n-3)}{2\cdot 6\cdots 2n}(1-\frac{f^2(x)}{c^2})^n \}.$

Comment: This works only if $|c^2-f^2(x)| \leq c^2$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the generalized binomial theorem:

If
$|x| < 1$ then
$(1+x)^a
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n}x^n
$
where
$\binom{a}{n}
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (a-k)}{n!}
$.

Therefore
$(1-x)^a
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n}(-1)^nx^n
$
where
$\binom{a}{n}
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (a-k)}{n!}
$.

If $a = \frac12$ then

$\begin{array}\\
(-1)^n\binom{\frac12}{n}
&=(-1)^n\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (\frac12-k)}{n!}\\
&=(-1)^n\dfrac{\frac1{2^n}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (1-2k)}{n!}\\
&=(-1)^n\dfrac{(-1)^n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2k-1)}{2^nn!}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2k-1)}{2^nn!}\\
&=\dfrac{-\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (2k-1)}{2^nn!}\\
&=\dfrac{-\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (2k-1)}{2^n\prod_{k=1}^n k}\\
&=\dfrac{-(1\cdot 3\cdot ... \cdot(2n-3)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6 ... \cdot (2n)}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I also have another question looking forward to help
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n}(-1)^n(1-\frac{f^2(x)}{c^2})^n$ whether to converge evenly or not

Comment: You want $|1-f^2(x)/c^2| < 1$ or $0 < f^2(x)/c^2 < 2$.

Comment: $|1-\frac{f^2(x)}{c^2}|\leq 1$